# Trying to get an if function to work in mips

Tags: mips

Hello new to using mars program and mips in general how would i got about after reading user input and its in an adress how do i use that to execute specific pieces of code?
Eg.

```
//get user input 
input = 1
if(input == 1)
//run this code
```

this is what i want to do, best way i could explain it (obviously in wrong format).
This is what i have up to now

````
```
typeinfo: .asciiz  " 1 - Cls \n 2 - Row \n 3 - Column \n 4 - Triangle \n 5 - Exit\n\n"
typetext: .asciiz "Enter a number here for type: "


#prints the options
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, typeinfo
syscall 

#prints out the prompt
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, typetext
syscall 

#i want to be able to run this if user inputs "1"
###########################################################


lui $s0, 0x1004
addi $t8, $zero, 0x00ff
addi $t0, $s0, 0
lui $s1, 0x100C

drawPixel: 
    sw $t8, 0($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    bne $t0, $s1, drawPixel

##########################################################
#gets the user input 
li $v0, 5
syscall

#move from $v0 to $t0
move $t1, $v0 

#ends program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```
````

Comment: That would typically be implemented using one or more conditional branches. E.g. `li $t0,1 bne $v0,$t0,endif ...do stuff... endif:`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ways you can compare registers (the register names I use are arbitrary, you can compare any two registers)

```
beq $t0,$t1,foo ;branch to label "foo" if t0 = t1

bne $t0,$t1,foo ;branch to label "foo" if t0 != t1


bltu $t0,$t1,foo ;branch to label "foo" if t0 < t1
blt $t0,$t1,foo 
;branch to label "foo" if t0 < t1 (numbers greater than 0x7FFFFFFF are treated as negative)

bleu $t0,$t1,foo ;branch to label "foo" if t0 <= t1
ble $t0,$t1,foo 
;branch to label "foo" if t0 <= t1 (numbers greater than 0x7FFFFFFF are treated as negative)

bgeu $t0,$t1,foo ;branch to label "foo" if t0 >= t1
bge $t0,$t1,foo
;branch to label "foo" if t0 >= t1 (numbers greater than 0x7FFFFFFF are treated as negative)

bgtu $t0,$t1,foo ;branch to label "foo" if t0 > t1
bgt $t0,$t1,foo
;branch to label "foo" if t0 > t1 (numbers greater than 0x7FFFFFFF are treated as negative)
```

Sometimes, the order in which you put your code isn't always straightforward, however. In the event you want to write:

```
input = 1;
if(input == 1)
  // do something, else do nothing
```

It's actually easier to reverse the branch condition, like so:

```
li $t1,1 ;constant one for comparing
li $t0,1 ;input
bne $t0,$t1, doNothing
; do something. This will be skipped if $t0 != $t1
doNothing:
```